# Datatables search and filter problem with quotation marks

Tags: datatables

I have problem with Datatables search by column or in general when variable has value like this
var = 'Company  "name" ';
When i searchin like name it works correctly, but when i paste exact value Company  "name" there is no results i guess the problem is in quotation marks maybe someone found solution? because those trings with quotation marks is in my DB.

Comment: I cannot recreate this issue. We probably need a [mre] to help you.

Comment: Having said that, it's worth double-checking in case your data is not actually using `"`, but instead is using different characters such as `”`. These so-called ["smart quotes"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090225-00/?p=19033) can creep into your data if Microsoft programs such as Excel and Word are used.

Comment: I checked my data it's using simple quotes not smart ones. 
as i said if there is word  with those quotes in center  of variable datatables search doesn't work at all if i change it without quotes it works perfect

Comment: Thank you for checking the double-quotes. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

My problem solution was use PHP. What I did changed array object property value using str_replace before pushing data to Datatables. So in db those values with quotation marks but when data goes to datatable those values without quotation marks